# Instantiating struct using constructor of embedded struct

Tags: go

I'm a Go newbie trying to override some methods in the AWS Go SDK for DynamoDB. Basically, I would like to add some logging to certain methods in the DynamoDB client. The code that I have is:

```
type dynamoDBLogger struct {
  dynamodb.DynamoDB
}

func (d *dynamoDBLogger) DeleteItemWithContext(ctx context.Context, item *dynamodb.DeleteItemInput) (*dynamodb.DeleteItemOutput, error) {
    logger.Debug("Deleting from DynamoDB: %+v", *item)
    return d.DynamoDB.DeleteItemWithContext(ctx, item)
}
```

In other words, it just adds a logging statement before the actual call. This code compiles. The problem is now how can I create a `dynamoDBLogger`? The only way to instantiate a `DynamoDB` is by using a method:

```
func New(...) *dynamodb.DynamoDB
```

in the `dynamodb` package. Can I somehow use that to build an instance of a `dynamoDBLogger`? Not sure if it'll work, but I would like for the `*dynamoDbLogger` type to be usable as a `*dynamodb.DynamoDB`.

EDIT: I actually noticed that the following fails:

```
func GetDynamoClient(sess *session.Session) *dynamodb.DynamoDB {
    svc := dynamoDBLogger{}
    svc.DynamoDB = *dynamodb.New(sess)
    return &svc
}
```

i.e. the type system doesn't allow substituting a `*dynamodb.DynamoDB` with a `*dynamoDBLogger`. I'm wondering if Go's type system allows what I'm trying to accomplish, since `dynamodb.DynamoDB` is not an interface?

Comment: Is dynamo.DynamoDB a type? The struct doesn't seem to provide a lot of information.

Comment: @AaqibBashir: Yes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB

Comment: Are you trying to use a logger to keep track of various levels inside this?

Comment: I have a ton of database code that assumes a `*dynamodb.DynamoDB` pointer as input. When running the software in debug mode, I would like for all DB queries to get dumped to logs. Without having to modify all the other code, I could just instantiate the `dynamodb.DynamoDB` pointer in the software config with my own extension. In other words, I just want to add logging statements to some of the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use dynamo db interface. It gives a possibility to create mocks for tests. Example:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbiface"
)

type dynamoDBLogger struct {
    DynamoDBAPI
}

func NewDynamoDB() dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI {
    svc := &dynamoDBLogger{
        DynamoDBAPI: dynamodb.New(sess),
    }
    return &svc
}

// in tests

type mockDB struct {
    dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI
}

func NewMockDB() dynamodbiface.DynamoDBAPI {
}
```

In mock you need to implement the only methods that actually is used in the program.

Full example is on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbiface/